# Broken Jquery Ui style Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I am trying to use a jquery UI date picker on a datefield in django.
but for some reason, it looks very bad. and the input field itself is wired.
I would like to know what I am doing wrong? how can I fix the view?
there is also (in green) a gap in the field how can I remove the gap?.

picture:
[image]

**JS**

```
 $("#id_start_time").datepicker({});
```

**my head of the page:**

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title></title>
```

```
<!--  Data Tables-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.6/css/rowReorder.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
        src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
        src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.6/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
        src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-+C0A5Ilqmu4QcSPxrlGpaZxJ04VjsRjKu+G82kl5UJk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.bootstrap3.min.css"
      integrity="sha256-ze/OEYGcFbPRmvCnrSeKbRTtjG4vGLHXgOqsyLFTRjg=" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see jQuery ui css there.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
```

Comment: Wich gap? Can you provide an image of it the way it is now?